# How to create delete url to delete row from table

Tags: magento-1.7, database

How  to create an URL for a link (on frontend),that ,when clicked, will call a function that deletes a row from the table.
Manually it works :)

```
public function deleteMessage($id) {
    Mage::getModel('blah/blah')->setId($id)->delete();
}
Mage::getModel('blah/blah')->deleteMessage(84);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to [create a controller action](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch) that accepts the delete id and authenticates that the user has the privileges to delete the data in question:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('delete_id');

        if($this->_canDelete($id)){
            try {
                Mage::getModel('blah/blah')->setId($id)->delete();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Error occurred: %s',$e->getMessage()));
                $this->_redirectReferer();
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Successfully deleted id %s',$id));


    }

    protected function _canDelete($id)
    {
        //not sure of your schema, probably something that checks if the current customer is allowed to delete:
        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        //do something
    }
}
```

However if this is in the admin your controller would be different and I suggest that you use the massaction delete instead.